# Fitting background image properly to a widescreen

Tags: html, css, image

Kind of weird title, but couldn't think of better way to word it.
Basically I'm working on a website, and I want to use an asset I made in photoshop for a navbar that looks like a leather suitcase/belt background. Issue is, if I stretch it too far, it won't fit the screen. Basically if I use the CSS `background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;` property, it looks something like this [image]

It fits nicely on the 100% width of the element, but as you can see, the image is clipped because it's not 100px as I want it to be.

If I used `background-size: contain; background-repeat: repeat-x;` properties my image would obviously fit nicely when it comes to height, but since it's not a *seamless texture* it doesn't clip properly horizontally. As seen on the image below:

[image]

Which looks pretty weird as you can see. Last but not least I tried using the 50% 50% trick - `background-position: 50% 50%; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;`, which kind of worked but i still have a problem with it not fitting vertically (the edges are being cut off), as you can see here:

[image]

So I'm asking if there's a way to fit the image properly with CSS that I'm missing. Alternatively the second image i posted with repeat-x, however if there would be a way to check (probably with javascript/jquery) that once the image doesn't fit (ala second image), it needs to be flipped horizontally with scaleX so the edges fit, or should I simply downscale the image in photoshop? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: If you can, create a working version on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
background-size: (100% 100%);
```

Comment: Would have the same effect as the first image but upside down (basically the bottom part having proper fitting, but the top part would be cropped)

Comment: It is not supposed to happen that way. It should give you the desired result. Can you please post the html n css of the element.

Comment: if it has solved your problem, please click on the tick on the left of this post so everyone can know that you have found your solution. Thanks.

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%; background-position: 0 0;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Try using viewport to give the element width in accordance with the screen width (100vw = 100% browser width).

```
.nav-belt {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Almost but not quite, doesn't cover the entire width of the screen for some reason, here's how it ended up looking: http://imgur.com/QpL53ex